# How to check each state value automatically and setState

Tags: reactjs

How to check if each state has value then combine all values?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   inputvalue : '',
      allval: ''
  }
 }
  
  onChangeOfInput =(name,value) =>{
   this.setState({
   [name]: value
  });
  }
  
  getValues = () =>{
   console.log(this.state);
    if(this.state.Title1) {
      this.setState({
        allval: this.state.allval+this.state.Title1
      });
    }
  }

 render() {
  return (
   <div className="hello">
    <Input onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}
     placeholder="Title 1" name="Title1" />
    <br/>
    <Input placeholder="Title 2" name="Title2"  onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} />
    <br/>
    <Input placeholder="Title 3" name="Title3"  onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
    <br/>
    <Input placeholder="Title 4" name="Title4"  onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
    <br/>
    <button onClick={this.getValues}>Get value</button>
    
   </div>
  )
 }
}

class Input extends React.Component  { 
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   inputvalue: ''
  }
 }

 handleChange(e) {
  
  this.setState({
   inputvalue: e.target.value
  });
    this.props.onChangeOfInput(this.props.name,e.target.value)
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
    value={this.state.inputvalue} 
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    />
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxm2ojLz/

The issue is here, I need to check each value `state.Title1`, `state.Title2`, `state.Title3`, `state.Title4` if they are not empty, then I want to combine all values if it is not empty and assign the combined values to `allVal`, how to combine all values to  `allval`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be doing something like this.

```
getValues = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    let combinedString = "";
    Object.keys(this.state)
        .map( igKey => {
        if(this.state[igKey] != "" && igKey.includes('Title')){
           combinedString = combinedString +''+ this.state[igKey];
           return combinedString
          }
        });
    this.setState({allval:combinedString})
    console.log(combinedString);
  }
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2nhc6drm/

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, each time I change to a new value, the result is attached the old value to the new value.

Comment: It's because allval state getting binded in combinedString, for this you need to check key like below : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4qakbb

Comment: Thanks, @jayvel edited my answer, that helped to make my answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Try handling `getValues` like this:

```
getValues = () =>{
    console.log(this.state);
    let result = [];
    Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => {
        if (key.includes('Title') && this.state[key]) result.push(`${key}: ${this.state[key]}`);
    })
    this.setState({
        allval: result.join('; ')
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Update **getValues** method :-

For concatination,it will ignore the keys *allval* and *inputval*.

```
   getValues = () => {
    let allval = ''
   for(let key of Object.keys(this.state)){

     if(key==='allval' || key==='inputval'){
       continue;
     }
     else{
       let value=this.state[key];
       console.log(value);
       if(value===''){

       }
       else{
           allval=allval+value;
       }
       console.log(allval);
     }
   }
   this.setState({allval:allval})
  }
```

Working SandBox :- https://codesandbox.io/s/vqoxo9w1wy

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use `reduce` for combinde the values, and use the functional `setState` to avoid double state change:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    allVal: '',
    title1: '',
    title2: ''
  }

  getValues = (prevState, name, newVal) => {
    return Object.keys(prevState)
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
      if (key === 'allVal') return acc;
      if (key === name) return acc + newVal;
      return acc + prevState[key];
     }, '')
  }
  
  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      [name]: value,
      allVal: this.getValues(prevState, name, value)
    }))
  }

  render(){
    const { title1, title2, allVal } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div>
        <input name="title1" onChange={this.handleChange} value={title1} /><br />
        <input name="title2" onChange={this.handleChange} value={title2} /><br />
        allVal: <span>{allVal}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```